# Дух сообщества может закрывать вопросы как дубликаты?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, дух-сообщества, дубликаты

[css анимация при добавлении класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445401/178988)

> отмечен как дубликат пользователями Qwertiy, Владимир, tutankhamun, Nick Volynkin, Дух сообщества ♦ 1 час назад

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит, когда автор соглашается с отметкой дубликата. То есть, если сам автор вопроса удовлетворен решением из другого вопроса, то нет смысла в дальнейшем голосовании. Тогда в дело вступает Дух и моментально утверждает отметку дубликата.

Можно увидеть, что [автор вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186217/nup) был на сайте как раз час назад — тогда же, когда в голосовании участвовал Дух.

В каком-то смысле Дух обладает [золотым Мьёлльниром](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/2790048) по абсолютно всем меткам.

Ещё он так может с предлагаемыми правками делать. В [описании метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/info) об этом есть пара слов.